# articles when not to use

Tags: articles

Which of the following sentences are correct?

1. Although it lives in all oceans and most seas, it prefers temperate and polar regions.
2. Although it lives in all oceans and most seas, it prefers the temperate and polar regions.

Comment: Joyce, if you don't find the answer you are looking for in the duplicate, please edit your question to provide more context and more information on what you find confusing. Also, you may find other helpful questions that already have answers by checking out the definite-article and article tags.

Answer (score 0):

Either would be understood in most situations as having the same meaning.

However, both do not have the same meaning.

> ...the temperate and polar regions.

refers to specific temperate and polar regions. This also implies that they exist.

> ...temperate and polar regions.

refers to temperate and polar regions in general. It could be used to mean that it prefers temperate and polar regions, but they don't exist.